# Extract values from Binary in Power BI

Tags: database, function, powerbi, dax, extract

I have the following table, and I want to replace the column value by the data inside each Binary row.

My table is:
[image]

And if i click in the Binary of the first row i get:
[image]

So, I want to extract that value, i.e., instead of the value Binary in the first row my table should show 434, and the same for each row.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom column to converter in desired format with below function:

```
Text.FromBinary([value])
```